# How to avoid HttpContext.Server.MapPath for Unit Testing Purposes

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-5, rhino-mocks

I am working in an ASP.net MVC 5 application. I would like to Unit Test my controller action which looks like this

```
public ActionResult Search()
{
  var vm = SetupSearchViewModel();

  return View(vm);
}
```

All the hard work is done by the `SetupSearchViewModel()` method, which itself is an orchestrator calling many different other methods, one of which is this

```
private string ExtractJsonFile(string filename)
{
  var filePath = HttpContext.Server.MapPath(filename);
  var json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);
  return json;
}
```

I plan on doing many Unit Tests on this particular action, but I'm starting with a very simple Unit Test which checks that the correct type of ActionResult is returned

```
[Test]
public void Search_Get_ReturnsViewResult()
{
  // arrange
  var performanceController = PerformanceControllerInstance;
  // act
  var result = performanceController.Search();
  //assert
  Assert.IsNotNull(result as ViewResult);
}
```

The test is failing because of the `ExtractJsonFile` method. It uses `HttpContext` and that is `null`. I am using Rhino Mocks to do the mocking of the various classes.

What would be the best way to Unit Test this? Darin in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377626/mock-httpcontext-current-server-mappath-using-moq) suggest we avoid `HttpContext.Current` if we want our code Unit Tested.

By the way I tried mocking the HttpContext and made it not null, but then the `Server` is `null`, I can go ahead and mock that too I suppose (I don't know how yet), but is there no better way? I've no problem doing major refactoring if needed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`HttpContext.Server.MapPath` would require an underlying virtual directory provider which would not exist during the unit test. Abstract the path mapping behind a service that you can mock to make the code testable.

```
public interface IPathProvider {
    string MapPath(string path);
}
```

In the implementation of the concrete service you can make your call to map the path and retrieve the file.

```
public class ServerPathProvider: IPathProvider {
    public string MapPath(string path) {
        return HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path);
    }
}
```

you would inject the abstraction into your controller or where needed and used

```
public MyController : Controller {

    public MyController(IPathProvider pathProvider) {
        this.pathProvider = pathProvider;
    }

    //...other code removed for brevity

    private string ExtractJsonFile(string filename) {
      var filePath = pathProvider.MapPath(filename);
      var json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);
      return json;
    }
}
```

Using your mocking framework of choice you can then mock the provider

```
[Test]
public void Search_Get_ReturnsViewResult() {
  // arrange
  IPathProvider mockedPathProvider = //...insert your mock/fake/stub here
  var performanceController = PerformanceControllerInstance(mockedPathProvider);
  // act
  var result = performanceController.Search();
  //assert
  Assert.IsNotNull(result as ViewResult);
}
```

and not be coupled to `HttpContext`

You could even go further and refactor the entire `ExtractJsonFile(string filename)` into its own service to get around being tied to disk as well.

```
public interface IJsonProvider {
    string ExtractJsonFile(string filename);
}
```

This service is now flexible enough to get the file from other sources like web service if needed.