# MVC Unit Testing - System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I am totally brand new to Unit Testing and am trying to learn off my own back. I have failed at the first hurdle and despite countless books and web sites I cannot see what I am doing wrong... Please can someone tell me?? I have an Action ViewResult as follows I am looking to test:

```
    public ViewResult ProductList()
    {
        List<ProductItem> allProducts = CallGetAllProducts();
        return View(allProducts);
    }
```

You can see it is calling a function:

```
    private List<ProductItem> CallGetAllProducts()
    {
        var productFilePath = Server.MapPath(@"~/CSV/products.csv");
        var products = new ProductsCSV();

        return (products.GetAllProductsFromCSV(productFilePath));
    }
```

Which is in turn calling the following function:

```
    public List<ProductItem> GetAllProductsFromCSV(string csvPath)
    {
        String[] csvData = File.ReadAllLines(csvPath);
        List<ProductItem> result = new List<ProductItem>();

        foreach (string csvrow in csvData)
        {
            var fields = csvrow.Split(',');
            ProductItem prod = new ProductItem()
            {
                ID = Convert.ToInt32(fields[0]),
                Description = fields[1],
                Item = fields[2][0],
                Price = Convert.ToDecimal(fields[3]),
                ImagePath = fields[4],
                Barcode = fields[5]
            };
            result.Add(prod);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

I have a Unit Test project I have created with the following test method in the appropriate ControllerTest file:

```
    [TestMethod()]
    public void ProductListGetsViewResult()
    {
        ProductsController controller = new ProductsController();
        ViewResult result = controller.ProductList() as ViewResult;
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    }
```

I have all the correct references setup as far as I can see, however the results of running this test are coming back with:

*Result Message:

Test method ShoppingBasket.Controllers.Tests.ProductsControllerTests.ProductListGetsViewResult threw exception: 
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*

It looks like the problem is with the calling of the ViewResult in the 'Act' part of the process... But Why, I dont know.

Comment: If I were faced with this, the first thing I would do is run the test in the debugger, and discover exactly which line of code is throwing the exception. Much better than guessing.

Comment: Also, my guess is that the exception is thrown in the `CallGetAllProducts` method, but without knowing what that code looks like, can't say more than that.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback hatchet... I have seen the debugger mode but havent got that far yet (total novice here). Could it just be that that the CallGetAllProducts is able to return a null causing it... I will post that function in the Q above in a moment... Thank

Comment: Get out the debugger and see which object is null. It will probably be something to do with the context the Unit Tests are run from, eg it uses a different .config file.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy.. I heeded your advice and debugger pointed me at the Server.MapPath call on the second code block down from above. I am intrigued where you say 'running from a different .config file... Could you spill any more knowledge on that to me please?

Comment: @CJH `Server.MapPath` is the cause of the problem. it is provided by IIS during run time but does not exist when testing as IIS is not available. Check the answer I gave here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38452743/how-to-avoid-httpcontext-server-mappath-for-unit-testing-purposes/38456288#38456288

Comment: @CJH you would also need to abstract the `File.ReadAllLines` IO access to be able to mock it and test in isolation.