# Mock hostingenvironment.mappath apicontroller c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, web-api-testing

I have some method which read the file by the path HostingEnvironment.MapPath("filepath"). From unit test HostingEnvironment.MapPath always returning null.

How can i setup the mock requestcontext to return proper file path in web api controller 2?

Comment: Change design to avoid tightly coupling to statics

Comment: Similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38452743/how-to-avoid-httpcontext-server-mappath-for-unit-testing-purposes/38456288#38456288